# how to return related data to a foreignkey django ajax

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, asynchronous

i have a project with two models one for computer features and the other for computer invoice

```
class ComputerFeature(models.Model):
    car_model = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    CPU = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    RAM = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    #others

class CustomerInvoice(models.Model):
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    model = models.ForeignKey(ComputerFeature, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

and this is my template

```html
<form method='POST'>{% csrf_token %}
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      
      {{ form.customer.errors }}
      <th class="float-left" id="customer">Customer  :  {{ form.customer  }}</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="form-group floating-label" id="modeling">
                            {{ form.model | add_class:'form-control select2-list ' | attr:'id:model'}}
                            
</div></td>

                
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {{ form.order.errors }}
      <td scope="col">quantity</td>
      <td scope="col" id="order">{{form.order}}</td>
                
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="col">CPU</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 50%" id="cpu">
      <--! i want to return CPU here before submiting the form -->
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td scope="col">RAM</td>
      <--! i want to return CPU here before submiting the form -->
    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {{ form.Hard.errors }}
      <td scope="col">Hard</td>
      <td scope="col" id="hard">{{form.model.Hard}}</td>
    
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="col">Graphic</td>
      <--! i want to return CPU here before submiting the form -->
    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {{ form.price.errors }}
      <td scope="col">price/td>
      <td scope="col" id="price">{{form.price}}</td>
    
    </tr>

  </thead>

</table>

<input type="submit" name="save" value="selling" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="submit">

</div>
</div>

</form>
```

i need to return CPU,RAM and other feature from ComputerFeature before submitting the form , recall them ?

and this is my form class

```
class CustomerInvoice(forms.ModelForm):
   model = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ComputerFeature.objects.all().order_by('-date'),empty_label='models')
   class Meta:
      model = CustomerInvoice
      fields = ['customer','model','price','order']
```

i know i should use ajax request , but i'm not sure how to achieve it!

thanks for helping

Comment: Please provide more details about your problem. It's too vague, it's hard to help. What did you try? What didn't work? What is the step where you got stuck?

Comment: @viam0Zah i have made a management system for a store , whenever we sell  a laptop model you know every laptop has its own features like (cpu,ram,graphic card etc..) whenever i select a laptop model , for exapmple mac pro book x , then before submitting the form , i want to display the selected laptop features (cpu,ram,graphic ..) , for make sure i have selected a correct model for sale . i'm not good at ajax , i couldnt do anything with it

Comment: @viam0Zah if you can help , please let me know , i need it